# A RenderFlex overflowed on the right in appbar

Tags: flutter

I have this error in the appbar :A RenderFlex overflowed by 122 pixels on the right.
how can fix it?
this is my code

```
appBar: AppBar(
      leading: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 7,
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 7,
          ),
          Text('Dashboard')
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
    ),
```

Comment: You're cramming a lot into a single appbar `leading` section. Move your `Row()` widget to `body:...`. See the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) for details on flutter's `AppBar()` widget.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. refer [**`AppBar`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

```
appBar: AppBar(
      leading: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 7,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      title: Text('Dashboard'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
    ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

1 year late to the party... faced the same issue. The trick here was to increase the `leadingWidth` property of the appbar. Oh and you need to put the text 'Dashboard' into its own title, like this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      leading: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 7,
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 7,
          )
        ],
      ),
      title: Text('Dashboard'),
      leadingWidth: 200, //Change this to whatever suits you
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
    ),
```